# RAS log analyzer (PPTP / L2TP VPN)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn, rras, logging

I'm looking for a free log analyzer for windows 2003 RAS logs, specifically VPN logs. My goal is to determine how many times a particular user connects.

I googled of course and found 100s of links, but I’m concerned about viruses without some feedback from real users.  Anyone used anything successfully?

Comment: What logging options do you have set?

Comment: All options currently

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. On the Logging tab of the RRAS server properties there are 4 radio buttons and 1 check box, which of these is selected?

Comment: log errors and warnings - unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IAS Log Viewer](http://deepsoftware.ru/iasviewer/) works well for IAS (including RADIUS) and RRAS.  There is a portable version with no install as well as installable.

It is shareware -- and can be used for free (as in beer).  If you like it, pay the developers to register it and unlock additional goodies.